# How to take n steps (iterations) in Python debugger (PyCharm)?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, conditional-breakpoint

I have a breakpoint in my Python debugger. I am using PyCharm. I want to iterate lets say 100 times to reach the point where I want to debug.

Now I can press 100 x times Resume Program, but is there a way to just execute a command to run n times over the breakpoint.

Comment: In your code, is it possible to monitor some variable that is related to the current loop counter? Like `for i in range(1000)`, you can track `i` then place a condition to enabling the breakpoint when `i == 100`, for example.

Comment: I could do that, but I am doing some time series analysis and it would be the most convenient if I could change on the go like +100, +200 ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a function in a conditional breakpoint to count iterations, take for example:

[image: conditional breakpoint image]

The conditional breakpoint can call a function which in addition to returning a boolean, counts the number of loop iterations.

```py
def your_counter(stop):
    global count
    count = count + 1
    if stop == count:
        # count = 0 for periodic break
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The solution shown is for cases when a one-liner condition might not be practical, and/or when a [loop counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Loop_counters) needs to be implemented externally. Since the breakpoint condition is programmatic you can implement it to break periodically, or on any series/frequency criteria you want to apply.

The custom condition would break at the exact iteration you want, after you're done "step debugging" either press resume, stop, "run to cursor", or disable the breakpoint right-clicking on it (in practice this gets you out of the loop).

You can also change the value of any variable in the middle of debugging by editing in "variable watches".

Answer (score 5):

PyCharm offers the possibility to add conditions on specific breakpoint. 
This feature is called *Conditional Breakpoints* and you can find the documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/conditional-breakpoints/).

I think that this is what you are looking for, because in this way you are able to enable the breakpoint only under specific conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I'm so happy I feel like crying...all those hours spent iterating through...I'm kicking myself for not searching this up earlier.

Comment: I feel you :) Glad to help you!